# Composite c1 "You should create at least one page type first" error mesage

Tags: c1-cms

I am using Composite C1 version 2.2.2
I am trying to add a new page and i am getting and error window:
Title - "No  page type available" 
Message - "You should create at least one page type first"
I have 2 page types defined and I added many pages to the system before.

I guess something went wrong, any ideas?

Comment: Check out your page types Settings tab, probably they are not Available (Layout -> edit Page Type -> Settings tab -> locate property Available -> make sure it is checked). Also checkout Availability tab, your page types may have some restrictions as "Homepage relation" or "Page type parent restriction"

Comment: @Inna you should make that comment as an answer :)

Comment: @Inna you should make that comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out your page types Settings tab, probably they are not Available (Layout -> edit Page Type -> Settings tab -> locate property Available -> make sure it is checked). Also checkout Availability tab, your page types may have some restrictions as "Homepage relation" or "Page type parent restriction"